# RWeka returns java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>

Tags: java, r, weka, rweka

I am trying to run Weka AODE class in R using RWeka.
The following code returns an error.

```
library("RWeka")
NB <- make_Weka_classifier("weka/classifiers/bayes/AODE")
classifier <- NB(Species ~ ., data = iris)
```

And I get this:

```
Error in .jnew("weka/core/Attribute", attname[i], .jcast(levels, "java/util/List")) : 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
```

I have verified that RWeka/java/RWeka.jar contains the AODE.class file.

when trying to run the naive bayes example in the RWeka manual in [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/index.html) I get the same error.

Any ideas why I get this error?

Comment: are you using the correct java version? i.e. 32 bits jave with 32 bits R or 64 bits jave with 64 bits R. Default of java install is 32 bits.

Comment: My java: OpenJDK 64-Bit. My R returned 8 on .Machine$sizeof.pointer, so I guess is 64 as well.